# Whom can I declare war on as a vassal of a vassal?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm a Count, to a Duke, to the Emperor.

I've managed to get a claim on a Count who is directly vassal of the Emperor, and the game informed me I can't declare war on him because we are both vassals but our liege is different.

Now, I know I can declare a war of independence against my Duke, so that's beside the point.

- If I get a claim on my Duke's County, can I declare a claim war on him?
- If I get a claim against an independent, can I declare a claim war on him?

Comment: Not directly addressed, but pertinent to your question title: you can declare war on other vassals of your direct liege. (From the rest of your question, it sounds like you've probably done this until the only holdings in the duchy are down to you and your liege; but I wanted to spell it out.) This is generally the safest and most reliable way to progress to a duchy, as holding a larger demesne than your liege makes your options for taking the duchy a lot more viable. Don't forget to check the factions you can create or join, especially after marriages, inheritance and succession law changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a claim on someone independent of the Empire you can declare war on him, so long as the Crown Authority is not Absolute.

If you get a claim on your Liege's County... That's a bit different. I do not believe you can directly declare a claim war against your Liege. **However**, once you have a claim on your Liege's Duke title (such a claim could be plot-fabricated) you can create a plot to demand the title from your Liege. Once you have a minimum of support (at least 80% plot power and at least 1 backer) you can state your demands to your liege. Your liege is very likely to reject your demands, at which point you will go to war for it.

---

I don't think you can make a claim war against your liege for his county title. Especially not when it's his only county.

The screenshot you shared is for the [Demand Duchy from Liege](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Decisions#Realm) Decision.
The plot I mentioned above is the [Gain Liege's Title](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Plot#Plots) Plot.

Comment: What if I get a claim on his (only) county, instead?

Comment: I fear this might not be possible, actually, http://i.imgur.com/CdbEifm.jpg due to the requirement "Can be given away". Since it's his primary title, I doubt he can give it away…

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the crown authority in your realm.

- You can declare war on independents, unless the crown authority is **Maximum** (but that's quite rare, especially in larger realms).
- You can declare war on other vassals of the same liege, as long as the crown authority is **Low or Minimum**.
- When you want to wage war against your liege, it has to be in form of a revolt. You can start one either through certain plots, or by forming a faction and then sending an ultimatum.

To check the crown authority in your realm, go to the "Laws" screen and click on the coat of arms of the topmost title (the empire in your case).